# Android kotlin do an Intent.ACTION_SEND inside the widget's configuration class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, android-widget

I have the following configuration class `MyWidgetConfigureActivity` for the widget, but I need to make sure that if an `"text/plain"` type `Intent.ACTION_SEND` as seen below occurs, it can do the same thing as I do on `MyWidgetConfigureActivity` to `onClickListener` to add the widget.

I also tried to put the same code in main, where it currently works, but as appWidgetId it gives me 0.

Can you give me a hand?

```kotlin
        val intent = intent
        val action = intent.action
        val type = intent.type

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND == action && type != null) {
            if ("text/plain" == type) {
                val widgetText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)
                ...call function
            }
        }
```

```kotlin
import android.app.Activity
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText

import com.myapp.test.databinding.MyWidgetConfigureBinding

/**
 * The configuration screen for the [MyWidget] AppWidget.
 */
class MyWidgetConfigureActivity : Activity() {
    private var appWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID
    private lateinit var appWidgetText: EditText
    private var onClickListener = View.OnClickListener {
        val context = this@MyWidgetConfigureActivity

        // When the button is clicked, store the string locally
        val widgetText = appWidgetText.text.toString()
        val urlCode = MyWidgetFunction().extractLinks(widgetText)
        Log.d("MyWidgetConfigureActivity-urlCode", urlCode)
        if (urlCode != "") {

            Log.d("MyWidgetConfigureActivity-appWidgetId", appWidgetId.toString())
            saveUrlPref(context, appWidgetId, urlCode)

            // It is the responsibility of the configuration activity to update the app widget
            val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)

            // Make sure we pass back the original appWidgetId
            val resultValue = Intent()
            resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue)
            finish()
        }
    }
    private lateinit var binding: MyWidgetConfigureBinding

    public override fun onCreate(icicle: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(icicle)
        // Set the result to CANCELED.  This will cause the widget host to cancel
        // out of the widget placement if the user presses the back button.
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED)

        binding = MyWidgetConfigureBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        appWidgetText = binding.appwidgetText as EditText
        binding.addButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener)

        // Find the widget id from the intent.
        val intent = intent
        val extras = intent.extras
        if (extras != null) {
            appWidgetId = extras.getInt(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID
            )
        }

        // If this activity was started with an intent without an app widget ID, finish with an error.
        if (appWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            finish()
            return
        }

        appWidgetText.setText(loadUrlPref(this@MyWidgetConfigureActivity, appWidgetId))
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Test"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyWidget"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name=".WidgetReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MyWidgetConfigureActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".WidgetService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```